# Why isn't a jQuery Tools tooltip showing up as a jQuery extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-tools, boilerplate

I have a Boilerplate 2.0-based page and want to add tooltips. Under the call to load jQuery, I add a call to load the jQuery-tools bundle, and then in js/script.js call:

```
jQuery(".has-tooltip").tooltip();
```

The result? No tooltips show up; Chrome's JavaScript console gives:

```
jQuery('.has-tooltip').tooltip();
script.js:30Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tooltip'
```

So far as I can tell, and from the order of things in index.html, the following happens:

1. I load jQuery.
2. I load jQuery Tools, without apparent error.
3. I call jQuery().tooltip(). This errors out, and doesn't display tooltips.

What can I do to ensure that the Tools extension is being registered to jQuery and I can call jQuery().tooltip(...)?

ATdhvaanckse,

--edit--

It's for a portfolio; the URL is:

http://JonathanHayward.com/portfolio

I've tried to pull things in to local loading (i.e. removed the CDN jQuery hit); this has not produced observable differences.

Comment: Check in fiddler to see if the tooltip js file is actually loaded.

Comment: You could verify that that the tooltip code is being loaded (using Firebug/whatever to inspect the set of loaded scripts); you could also post your HTML, even if it's very boring, just to be complete (and who knows, maybe there's something simple wrong with it).

Comment: You use conditional comments to insert your opening `<html>` tag but what happens if the visitor is not using Explorer; no `<html>` tag at all?  Also according to the W3C Validator you have six stray `</div>` tags.

Comment: So what happened here?  Any resolution?

Comment: Per the answer below, I was loading jQuery, then loading jQuery Tooltips, then loading jQuery again, overwriting the loaded jQuery Tooltips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, You load jQuery twice, also have two body and html closing tags and fix Modernizr issue which is not defined